# removing items in a variable, jquery

Tags: jquery

Here's the code:

```
var $type = $('#services, #reseller,#technology,#referral'); 
$type.click(function() {
$('#region-nav-reseller').hide();
```

I can hide #region-nav-reseller when I click on $type (#services, #reseller, #technology or #referral).

This works great, but what about if I would like to exclude #technology and #reseller when I click on $type?

I image something like:

```
$type-$('#technology, #reseller').click(function() {
    $('#region-nav-reseller').hide();
```

But this doesn't work (duh ;) )

Comment: Couldn't you just remove them from the variable itself? so `var $type = $('#services,#referral');`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding your problem correctly, then jQuery's `[.not()][1]` function should be able to help you. Try:

```
$($type).not('#technology, #reseller').click(...);
```

It seems you have a specific purpose in mind for the group of those four IDs. Another idea would be to separate out the things that are clickable from that group. Consider:

```
var clickable = $("#technology, #reseller");
var nonClickable = $("#services, #referral");
var everything = $(clickable).and(nonClickable);

// Now you can do different things with these different sets
$(everything).whatever();
$(clickable).click(...);
```

Comment: Because it's easier for people to understand :) But yes, it's redundant. `$type.not(...)` is faster/less expensive, and has the exact same effect.

Answer (score 2):

```
$type.click(function(ev) {
    if (this.id !== 'technology' && this.id !== 'reseller') {
        $('#region-nav-reseller').hide();
    }
});
```